# Why is my props undefined when i passed a defined state through?

Tags: ecmascript-6, components, reactjs

I am trying to pass data to a child component and I keep getting an undefined prop. I think it may have an issue with when Im setting the state in the parent component. Should i not be using componentWillMount?

```
export default class AllItems extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state=({ user: cookie.load('user')})
    this.httpHandler = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': this.state.user.token
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.httpHandler('/products/')
    .then(function (response) {
      this.setState({ winks: response.data.data})
      console.log(this.state.winks)
    }.bind(this))
  }
  render() {
    return (

              <Winks products={this.state.winks} />

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your promise may not return before `componentWillMount` finishes and `render` is called. So `products` won't exist yet. You could do something like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.winks) {
    return (<Winks products={this.state.winks} />)
  } else {
    return (<div>No Winks yet</div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you do not have an initial state for winks Since you are relying on an ajax call to set the state of winks, the ajax call will take place asynchronously and then it will execute the render function before the api call finishes causing this.state.winks to be undefined initially.

You could do something like this

```
render() {
  let content = this.state.winks ? <Winks products={this.state.winks} /> : <div/>
  return <div> {content} </div>
```